# Multicore (autosar)

Tags: multicore, autosar

I am working on enhanced BSW allocation (multicore).
I have two codes running on different cores, both will have different build, i.e., two elf files. I want both the cores to communicate in this case without the use of IOC and RTE using shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to hook such HW sync mechanisms maybe by ISRs to ExternalTriggerEvents in the RTE of each, or by some ComplexDriver doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Semaphores are one thing. Take a look at NXP's [AN4805](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN4805.pdf?&fpsp=1&WT_TYPE=Application%20Notes&WT_VENDOR=FREESCALE&WT_FILE_FORMAT=pdf&WT_ASSET=Documentation&fileExt=.pdf), which is for PowerPC hardware architecture but gives a good idea what's in it.

> A semaphore is a variable or abstract data type that provides a simple
>   but useful abstraction for controlling access by multiple processes to
>   a common resource in a parallel programming or multi-user environment.
>   Semaphores are the predominant method in access control in parallel
>   programming and multi-threaded programming environments since their
>   invention in 1965 by the late Edsger Dijkstra, a Dutch computer
>   scientist. Although the semaphore concept was further enhanced from
>   its original principle into many variations, they all serve a similar
>   purpose: to grant access to shared resources without race conditions.
>   ...

Then there is also [OpenAMP](http://www.multicore-association.org/workgroup/oamp.php), but I have not seen it around in the AUTOSAR context.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing according to AUTOSAR, then you may want to read what AUTOSAR specifies for Multi-core System development.

[AUTOSAR_EXP_MultiCoreGuide.pdf](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/4-1/AUTOSAR_EXP_MultiCoreGuide.pdf)